# Is there a way to create a script in Google Sheets to print 2 copies of the active sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google Sheet for business use and I would like to create a button that prints 2 copies of the active sheet. The reason for this is because this needs to happen multiple times per day and it is very repetitive. Is there a script that I can use to attach to a button to achieve this goal? I have read that printing in Google Sheets is not very user friendly.

Comment: Is this your second profile ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/65265245/11225291? Either way this is a duplicate post.

Comment: No, I do not have 2 profiles. Thank you for showing me this other post as I did not see it earlier when I made my post. I am hoping that we can get an answer to this question.